# How to make a table with three columns?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to make a table with three columns containing the values of p, q and W. I have written the following code which gives multiple columns. I have tried Flattening the table. but I could not find where to use it and so, instead of giving a table of three columns it gives a single column of data

```
W[nn_, q_, p_] := (-1)^nn (1/\[Pi]) E^-(p^2 + q^2) LaguerreL[nn, 2 (p^2 + q^2)]

w = Table[Table[Table[{q, p, W[nn, q, p]}, {q, -1, 1, 0.1}], {p, -1, 1, 0.1}], {nn, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: A little rearrangement of your code; see if you can use this: `{w1, w2} = 
  Flatten[#, 2] &@
     Table[{q, p, W[nn, q, p]}, {q, -1, 1, 0.1}, {p, -1, 1, 
       0.1}, {nn, {#}}] & /@ {1, 2};` and `TableForm /@ {w1, w2}` and for plotting: `ListPlot3D [#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {w1, w2}`

Comment: (Also note that you don't need to write `Table[Table[Table[...`; you can just list the iterators one after another, e.g. `Table[f[i,j,k], {i,1,5}, {j,1,7}, {k,1,4}]`!)

Comment: Note that `Flatten[w,2]` will flatten everything into a single column of data, but you will lose the distinction between different values of `nn`; `Transpose[Flatten[w, {2,3}]]` will flatten the `p` and `q` levels together, and then swap things so you have a list for `nn` = `1` and a list for `nn` = `2`, which is equivalent to Syed's answer (except the nesting of iteration over `p` and `q` are essentially swapped). Just thought I'd offer a different way of doing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w = Flatten[#, 2] &@Table[{q, p, W[nn, q, p]}, {q, -3, 3, 0.1}, {p, -3, 3, 0.1}, {nn, 2,2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Do`:

```
array = {};
Do[AppendTo[array, {q, p, W[nn, q, p]}], {q, -1, 1, 0.1}, {p, -1, 1, 0.1}, {nn, 1, 2}]
array
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, perhaps more functional, way would be using [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) and [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
w= {#1, #2, W[#3, #1, #2]} & @@@ 
  Tuples[{Range[-1, 1, 0.1], Range[-1, 1, 0.1], Range[1, 2]}];
```